# Redirecting to parentpage using an Iframe with a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

Working in ASP.NET MVC 2.

I have a page that opens a Iframe.
On that IFrame I have a form. When I click submit I redirect to a controller.

How can I show the result of that controller on the parent page and not in the IFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting

> target = "_parent"

in the form, was the solution